# Observable instance emit without an observer (or subscriber ?)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I am using observable in Angular2. As I know so far, each Observable instance come with an observer(1:1), and when we emit something with observer.next(value) we can get that value with observable.subscribe((value) => {}).

```js
var observable = Observable.create(observer => {
  observer.next(value);
}
.map(value=>{})
.catch(...)
observable.subscribe(value => {
  console.log(value);
})
```

How can I emit value without knowing the corresponding observer, because I want to emit value outside create function. One possible solution is save observer into some global variable but I think an observable should be enough. Any suggestion for this ??

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like [`Subject`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/subject.md)?

Comment: Oh, It looks like this can be done using Subject instead of Observable, Thank you very much!! I will take time to look at it further. Or I think maybe I can create a class doing what I need :)

Comment: Subject is the way to go. Also note that it is not a 1:1, you can subscribe multiple times

Comment: Oh my mistake, I thought that every time we subscribe there's only one observer, but turn out that each subscribe create one different observer. Terrible misunderstanding ><!!

Comment: Indeed. Subject is the one you need to use. It is equivalent to q.defer() in angular 1. In your function you then return the subject, which is equ ivalent to defer.promise. Also defer.reject = subject.error(), subject.next= defer.resolve

Comment: Thank you @hannesneukermans!
Can I use map with `Subject` ?

Comment: @dttung1412 : since Subject implements Observable you can use any 'Observable' method on a subject .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're mixing multiple things together. Observables are not in 1:1 relation with Observers (more precisely it's 1:N). If you want to be able to manually emit values you need a [`Subject`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) which acts as an Observable and an Observer at the same time. Practically this means you can call its `next()` method and it'll propage the value to all its subscribers (Observers).

For example consider the following code in TypeScript:

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

let source = new Subject();

source.subscribe(val => console.log('Observer 1:', val));
source.subscribe(val => console.log('Observer 2:', val));

source.next(42);
source.next('test');
```

This will print to console:

```
Observer 1: 42
Observer 2: 42
Observer 1: test
Observer 2: test
```

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/gWMFMnPlLJVDC1pQi8pH?p=preview

Read more:

- http://reactivex.io/intro.html
- https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS#resources
- https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/creating.md

Be aware that [`Observable.create()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-create) is a very different animal. It takes as a parameter a function that is **called every time a new Observer subscribes**. That's why it take the newly subscribed Observer as an argument. In this function you can for example call `next()` method on the Observer to send it some default value that all subscribes need to receive.

So you probably want to use `Subject` instead of `Observable.create()`.

Comment: Thank you for your detail answer but a little more confuse that can I use `map` operation with `Subject`

Comment: @dttung1412 Of course you can. `Subject` extends `Observable` so it has all the operators as `Observable` http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subject.js~Subject.html